# PHP7 sessions not saving even though PHPSESSID is the same

Tags: php, session

What makes me wonder is "PHPSESSID" is not changing, so the session is set.

When I delete my cookies and refresh the page "PHPSESSID" gets change.

here's my code:

```
if (!is_writable(session_save_path())) {
    echo 'Session path "'.session_save_path().'" is not writable for PHP!';
} // checking if its the problem but it's not. 

if (!isset($_SESSION['started'])) { 
// i've tried with session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE but with the 
// same result
    session_start();
    echo 'session started<br>';
    $_SESSION['started'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['test']= 'TestValue<br>';
}

echo ($_SESSION['test']) ?? 'Nothing Found<br>';
```

The output is always :

```
session started
TestValue
```

PHP Version: 7.1.13

System: Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$_SESSION` is only available if [`session_start()`](https://secure.php.net/session_start) was called.

So `if (!isset($_SESSION['started'])) {` will always be true.

You should use :

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['started'])) { 
    $_SESSION['started'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['test']= 'TestValue<br>';
}
```